# How can I prevent the text from the second column from moving? as per the picture shown

Tags: html, css

I have a span id text under the email field to valid the email address being keyed in. If an invalid email is being entered, a text `"invalid email"` will appear and it will shift the next column text moving right.

I use "     ...." to separate between first text column textbox and the text besides it.

Problem with the text :

[image]

CSS code:

```
.txtbox {
        text-align: right;
        display:inline-block;
        width: 250px;
        font-family: arial;  
    }

.righttxtbox {
        margin: 5px;
        width: 250px;
        font-family: arial;
    }
```

HTML code:

```
<div>   
     <asp:Label ID="Label3" font-size="12pt" forecolor="White" font name="arial" runat="server" Text="Email:" CssClass="lefttxt"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_AppEmail" runat="server" onkeyup="EmailCheck()" CssClass="txtbox"></asp:TextBox>
             <span id="error" style="display: inline-block; color: white"></span>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;               
            
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" font-size="12pt" forecolor="White" font-name="arial" runat="server" Text="SBU/DEPT:" CssClass="righttxt1"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="appDropDownSBU" runat="server" width="254px" CssClass="righttxtbox">
                <asp:ListItem>Electronics</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Others</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
```

Comment: `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` But it will be better if you show the code. html and css

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I have updated with the Css and html code